# django project with twisted and run as "Daemon"

Tags: django, twisted, daemon

Last two day I'm trying to find a way to run a working django project under twisted. After detailed searching I found several methods to configure it. But most of them are deal with how to run the app via command line not as a daemon.I want to run the django project as daemon.

I tried following links to implement this,

1. [Twisted: Creating a ThreadPool and then daemonizing leads to uninformative hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875326/twisted-creating-a-threadpool-and-then-daemonizing-leads-to-uninformative-hangs)
2. http://www.robgolding.com/blog/2011/02/05/django-on-twistd-web-wsgi-issue-workaround/

But this also not working for me.By this method TCP server is not even listen to the given port.

Please help me to figure it out.

## UPDATE

I'm sorry for the missing informations.Here is my objectives.

I'm beginner in twisted world, so first I'm trying to get my working django project configured under twisted,currently its working well on django testing server or apache via mod_wsgi.

To configure it with twisted I used the biding code given below, that code is a combination of two sample's found in the links that I given in the first post.

So in-order to integrate django app with twisted I used the following code, file name: "server.py".

```
import sys
import os

from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.web import server, resource, wsgi, static
from twisted.python import threadpool
from twisted.internet import reactor
from django.conf import settings
import twresource # This file hold implementation of "Class Root".


class ThreadPoolService(service.Service):
    def __init__(self, pool):
        self.pool = pool

    def startService(self):
        service.Service.startService(self)
        self.pool.start()

    def stopService(self):
        service.Service.stopService(self)
        self.pool.stop()

class Root(resource.Resource):
    def __init__(self, wsgi_resource):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
        self.wsgi_resource = wsgi_resource

    def getChild(self, path, request):
        path0 = request.prepath.pop(0)
        request.postpath.insert(0, path0)
        return self.wsgi_resource

PORT = 8080

# Environment setup for your Django project files:
#insert it to first so our project will get first priority.
sys.path.insert(0,"django_project")
sys.path.insert(0,".")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

def wsgi_resource():
    pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
    pool.start()
    # Allow Ctrl-C to get you out cleanly:
    reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('after', 'shutdown', pool.stop)
    wsgi_resource = wsgi.WSGIResource(reactor, pool, WSGIHandler())
    return wsgi_resource


# Twisted Application Framework setup:
application = service.Application('twisted-django')

# WSGI container for Django, combine it with twisted.web.Resource:
# XXX this is the only 'ugly' part: see the 'getChild' method in twresource.Root

wsgi_root = wsgi_resource()
root = Root(wsgi_root)

#multi = service.MultiService()
#pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
#tps = ThreadPoolService(pool)
#tps.setServiceParent(multi)
#resource = wsgi.WSGIResource(reactor, tps.pool, WSGIHandler())
#root = twresource.Root(resource)


#Admin Site media files
#staticrsrc = static.File(os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), "/usr/haridas/eclipse_workplace/skgargpms/django/contrib/admin/media/"))
#root.putChild("admin/media", staticrsrc)

# Serve it up:
main_site = server.Site(root)
#internet.TCPServer(PORT, main_site).setServiceParent(multi)
internet.TCPServer(PORT, main_site).setServiceParent(application)

#EOF.
```

Using above code It worked well from command line using "twisted -ny server.py", but when we run it as daemon "twisted -y server.py" it will hang, but the app is listening to the port 8080. I can access it using telnet.

I found some fixes for this hanging issue from stackoverflow itself. It helped me to use the code sections given below, which is commented in the above server.py file.

```
multi = service.MultiService()
pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
tps = ThreadPoolService(pool)
tps.setServiceParent(multi)
resource = wsgi.WSGIResource(reactor, tps.pool, WSGIHandler())
root = twresource.Root(resource)
```

and :-

```
internet.TCPServer(PORT, main_site).setServiceParent(multi)
```

instead of using the:-

```
wsgi_root = wsgi_resource()
root = Root(wsgi_root)
```

and :-

```
internet.TCPServer(PORT, main_site).setServiceParent(application)
```

The modified method also didn't helped me to avoid the hanging issue.Is any body out there who successfully run the django apps under twisted daemon mode?.

I maid any mistakes while combining these codes?, Currently I'm only started to learn the twisted architectures in detail. Please help me to solve this problem

Thanks and Regards,

Haridas N.

Note:- Im looking for the Twisted Application configuration (TAC) file, which integrate django app with twisted and run with out any problem in the daemon mode also.

Thank you,
Haridas N.

Answer (score 1):

**twistd** is the *Twisted Daemonizer*.  Anything you run with `twistd` will be easy to daemonize.  All you have to do is *not* pass the `--nodaemon` option.

As far as why your code is "not working", you need to provide more details about what you did, what you expected to happen, and how what actually happened differed from your expectations.  Otherwise, only a magician can answer your question.

Since you said the TCP port doesn't even get set up, the only guess I can think of is that you're trying to listen on a privileged port (such as 80) without having permissions to do so (ie, you're not root and you're not using [authbind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind) or something similar).