# Twisted hangs while daemonize

Tags: django, twisted, comet

I'm beginner in twisted world, so first I'm trying to get my working django project configured under twisted,currently its working well on django testing server or apache via mod_wsgi.

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875326/twisted-creating-a-threadpool-and-then-daemonizing-leads-to-uninformative-hangs) and [this too](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/realtime-web-apps-python-django-orbited-twisted) to configure the setup, based on that I have a server.py file given bellow

So in-order to integrate django app with twisted I used the following code,

```
import sys
import os

from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.web import server, resource, wsgi, static
from twisted.python import threadpool
from twisted.internet import reactor
from django.conf import settings
import twresource # This file hold implementation of "Class Root".


class ThreadPoolService(service.Service):
    def __init__(self, pool):
        self.pool = pool

    def startService(self):
        service.Service.startService(self)
        self.pool.start()

    def stopService(self):
        service.Service.stopService(self)
        self.pool.stop()

class Root(resource.Resource):
    def __init__(self, wsgi_resource):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
        self.wsgi_resource = wsgi_resource

    def getChild(self, path, request):
        path0 = request.prepath.pop(0)
        request.postpath.insert(0, path0)
        return self.wsgi_resource

PORT = 8080

# Environment setup for your Django project files:
#insert it to first so our project will get first priority.
sys.path.insert(0,"django_project")
sys.path.insert(0,".")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

def wsgi_resource():
    pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
    pool.start()
    # Allow Ctrl-C to get you out cleanly:
    reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('after', 'shutdown', pool.stop)
    wsgi_resource = wsgi.WSGIResource(reactor, pool, WSGIHandler())
    return wsgi_resource


# Twisted Application Framework setup:
application = service.Application('twisted-django')

# WSGI container for Django, combine it with twisted.web.Resource:
# XXX this is the only 'ugly' part: see the 'getChild' method in twresource.Root

wsgi_root = wsgi_resource()
root = Root(wsgi_root)

#multi = service.MultiService()
#pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
#tps = ThreadPoolService(pool)
#tps.setServiceParent(multi)
#resource = wsgi.WSGIResource(reactor, tps.pool, WSGIHandler())
#root = twresource.Root(resource)


#Admin Site media files
#staticrsrc = static.File(os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), "/usr/haridas/eclipse_workplace/skgargpms/django/contrib/admin/media/"))
#root.putChild("admin/media", staticrsrc)

# Serve it up:
main_site = server.Site(root)
#internet.TCPServer(PORT, main_site).setServiceParent(multi)
internet.TCPServer(PORT, main_site).setServiceParent(application)

#EOF.
```

Using above code It worked well from command line using "twisted -ny server.py", but when we run it as daemon "twisted -y server.py" it will hang, but the app is listening to the port 8080. I can access it using telnet.

I found some fixes for this hanging issue from stackoverflow itself. It helped me to use the code sections given below, which is commented in the above server.py file.

```
multi = service.MultiService()
pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
tps = ThreadPoolService(pool)
tps.setServiceParent(multi)
resource = wsgi.WSGIResource(reactor, tps.pool, WSGIHandler())
root = twresource.Root(resource)
```

and :-

```
internet.TCPServer(PORT, main_site).setServiceParent(multi)
```

instead of using the:-

```
wsgi_root = wsgi_resource()
root = Root(wsgi_root)
```

and :-

```
internet.TCPServer(PORT, main_site).setServiceParent(application)
```

The modified method also didn't helped me to avoid the hanging issue.Is any body out there who successfully run the django apps under twisted daemon mode?.

I maid any mistakes while combining these codes?, Currently I'm only started to learn the twisted architectures in detail. Please help me to solve this problem

I'm looking for the Twisted Application configuration (TAC) file, which integrate django app with twisted and run with out any problem in the daemon mode also.

Thanks and Regards,

Haridas N.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are almost there. Just add one more line at the very end:

```
multi.setServiceParent(application)
```

Comment: Yeah !, The only missing thing is that line. Now things working well without any blocking ....
Thank YOu.

Comment: StackOverflow needs to do a better job at pestering question posters to accept an answer (subtle reminders like what Amazon and Ebay do would be nice). Some folks always remember to accept, some do not. :-/